# Is it possible to swap out the JavaExecAction Gradle is using to run Java?

Tags: java, gradle

Java fails to launch when the classpath is too long. The length limit is particularly short on Windows.

Gradle seem uninterested in fixing the issue on their side (even though it's sort of their responsibility since they're the ones launching Java), so we ended up substituting the `JavaExec` task out with our own alternative.

The alternative works like this:

```
public class WorkingJavaExec extends JavaExec {
    private static final String MATCH_CHUNKS_OF_70_CHARACTERS =
        "(?<=\\G.{70})";

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void exec() {
        FileCollection oldClasspath = getClasspath();
        File jarFile = null;
        try {
            if (!oldClasspath.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    jarFile =
                        toJarWithClasspath(oldClasspath.getFiles());
                    setClasspath(getProject().files(jarFile));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }

            super.exec();
        } finally {
            setClasspath(oldClasspath);

            if (jarFile != null) {
                try {
                    Files.delete(jarFile.toPath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.warn("Couldn't delete: " + jarFile, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static File toJarWithClasspath(Set<File> files)
            throws IOException {
        File jarFile = File.createTempFile("long-classpath", ".jar");
        try (ZipOutputStream zip =
                new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jarFile))) {
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
            try (PrintWriter writer =
                    new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                            zip, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                writer.println("Manifest-Version: 1.0");
                String classPath = files.stream().map(
                        file -> file.toURI().toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
                String classPathEntry = "Class-Path: " + classPath;
                writer.println(Arrays.stream(
                    classPathEntry.split(MATCH_CHUNKS_OF_70_CHARACTERS))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n ")));
            }
        }
        return jarFile;
    }
}
```

Using this is cumbersome, though, because everywhere someone might run `JavaExec`, I have to replace it with `WorkingJavaExec`. New developers also don't know that there is this pitfall in Gradle in the first place, so they don't even know it's something they have to work around.

In reading the internals of Gradle, I saw that `JavaExec` internally uses a `JavaExecAction` to do the actual exec.

I thought that maybe by replacing this, we could fix the problem as if Gradle had fixed it themselves, and maybe it would then also apply to other tasks, such as `Test`. But I haven't been able to find any examples anywhere. (Even in other large projects, which you would expect to have hit the same issue!)

Is it possible to substitute `JavaExecAction`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can "substitute" `JavaExecAction` because it is set during JavaExec task instanciation, but I think you can solve this problem in a nicer way, using a custom **Plugin** as follow:

```
class FixClasspathLimitPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        // after project has been evaluated, hack into all tasks of type JavaExec declared.
        project.afterEvaluate {

            project.tasks.stream().filter { task -> task instanceof JavaExec }.forEach {
                println "Reconfiguring classpath for :  $it"
                JavaExec javaExec = (JavaExec) it;
                FileCollection oldClasspath = javaExec.getClasspath()

                // insert an Action at first position, that will change classpath
                javaExec.doFirst { task ->
                    ((JavaExec) task).setClasspath(getProject().files(toJarWithClasspath(oldClasspath.getFiles())));
                }
                // optional - reset old classpath
                javaExec.doLast { task ->
                    ((JavaExec) task).setClasspath(oldClasspath)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static File toJarWithClasspath(Set<File> files)
        throws Exception {

        // same method implementation as given in your question

    }
```

This way, you won't have to replace *JavaExec* in all build scripts written by your team, you will only have to ensure that these scripts apply your plugin.

And if you use a custom distribution of Gradle and use wrapper in you enterprise, you can even include this plugin in this distribution as an Init Script, as explained here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script

> Put a file that ends with .gradle in the GRADLE_HOME/init.d/ directory, in the Gradle distribution. This allows you to package up a custom Gradle distribution containing some custom build logic and plugins. You can combine this with the Gradle wrapper as a way to make custom logic available to all builds in your enterprise.

This way, the plugin will be applied in a "transparent" way.

Concerning the `Test` task: it does not use `JavaExecAction`, I think, but a similar solution could be applied, using a similar plugin.

Comment: There's definitely some merit in doing this as a plugin either way, I think, because it reduces the amount of work people have to do to include the workaround. It's a lot messier than just JavaExec though, because all other tasks using the JavaExecAction would need changing too, and I'm not entirely sure how I can figure out the complete list of misbehaving tasks. :( Also, I think if we were going to make a custom Gradle distribution, the best solution is probably to modify JavaExecAction itself to work properly without modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jar` task to add the class path to the manifest for you:

```
jar {
    baseName = "my-app"
    version =  "1.0.0"
    manifest {
        attributes("Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}
```

And then you can reference that jar when launching:

```
task run(type:JavaExec) {
    classpath = jar.outputs.files
    main = "myapp.MainClass"
}
```

That works around the command line path limit. You might also want to copy the dependency JARs to the output folder, so they will be available at runtime.

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy, dependsOn: [ "build" ]) {
   from configurations.runtime
   into "./build/libs"
}

build.finalizedBy(copyDependencies)
```

Helpful?

Comment: I think I will avoid modifying the Class-Path inside the jar itself, because as soon as the project gets packaged up, the path will be wrong again, and I've noticed in the past that the JVM will try to resolve the jars on the Class-Path even when you're not using `java -jar`, which used to slow down startup and produce unnecessary warnings. So this sort of approach would work best if we made a separate jar with the workaround in it to avoid modifying the main jar that ends up being distributed.